# Toric vector bundle - Klyachko's classification

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, algebraic-groups, toric-varieties, algebraic-vector-bundles

I am trying to understand Klyachko's classification of toric vector bundles on a toric variety ( his article: Equivariant vector bundles on toric varieties and some problems of linear algebra). I am reading Sam Payne's version of it as presented in the preliminaries of his article Moduli of Toric Vector Bundles. I am having some troubles understanding two things. The setting:

Let $N$ be a lattice, $M = \text{Hom}(N,\mathbb{Z})$ the dual lattice, $\Delta$ a fan in $N \otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{R}$, $ X = X(\Delta)$ the corresponding toric variety and $\mathscr{E}$ a toric vector bundle on $X$. An algebraic action of the torus $T$ on $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{E})$, the vector space of global sections, is given by
$$ (t\cdot s)(x) = t(s(t^{-1}x))$$
for $t\in T, s\in\Gamma(X,\mathscr{E})$ and $x\in X$.
So far so good.

This action induces the following decomposition into T-eigenspaces
$$ \Gamma(X,\mathscr{E}) = \oplus_{u\in M}\Gamma(X,\mathscr{E})_u, $$
where
$$ t\cdot s = \chi^{u}(t)s$$
for  $t\in T$ and $s\in \Gamma(X,\mathscr{E})_u$.

Question 1:
Why does this decomposition exist? I have read (Cox, Toric Varieties Porp 1.1.2) that, for an algebraic action, such a decomposition exists if the action is linear and the vector space is of a finite dimension. I see that the above action is linear but cannot see why the vector space $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{E})$ is finite dimensional.

Question 2: I know that for $u\in M$ the character $\chi^{u}$ is a regular function on $X$. I don't understand why in the above setting, the eigenfuction $\chi^{u}$ is an element of $\Gamma(X, O_X)_{-u}$

Additional questions (after the above were answered thanks to sti9111)
Continuing my pursue of understanding Klyachko's theorem, I am trying to understand the following point mentioned both in Payne (p.7) and in Gonzalez (p. 7).
Continuing with Payne's notation let $E$ be the fiber at the identity element of the Torus, $x_0$. Consider the map $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{E})_u\to E$ given by the evaluation at $x_0$. For $\sigma\in\Delta$, denote with $E^{\sigma}_{u}$ the image of $\Gamma(U_\sigma,\mathscr{E})_u$ under this evaluation map. For a ray $\rho\in\Delta$, we denote with $E^{\rho}(i)=E^{\rho}_{u}$ for any $u$ such that $<u,v_\rho>=i$.

My question: both in Payne's proof of Klyachko's classification theorem (p.7) and in Gonzalez's article (p.7), the fllowing is mentioned
$E^{\sigma}_{u}=\cap_{\substack{\rho\preceq\sigma}}E^{\rho}(<u,v_\rho>)$ and in Gonzalez, the image of $H^{0}(X,\mathscr{E})_u$ under the evaluation map is equal to $\mathscr{E}^{\rho1}(<u,v_1>)\cap\dots\cap\mathscr{E}^{\rho_{d}}(<u,v_d>)$.
I cannot see why this holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explain the Toric vector bundle - Klyachko's decomposition here could be a little bit difficult, however, I think that the paper "Okounkov bodies on projectivizations of rank two toric vector bundles" by Jose Luis Gonzalez, on pages 6 and 7 gives a good explanation.  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I already came across it. He mentions more or less what is stated in Payne's article but without getting into details and hence not answering my questions. My 2 questions are very concrete. I mentioned Klyachko's decomposition not in order to get an explnation for it but just to give a general background. I would hence appreciate concrete answers or references that directly answer my questions.

Comment: Hi, :) I think that at least the Question 1 has an explanation in the unswer above, because  only remains to show that for different  $u,v$ in M the isotypical vector spaces $H^0(U,E)_u$ and  $H^0(U,E)_v$ only intersects in the identity function, on a open set $U$. Similarly, for the second question $E=\mathcal{O}_X$, then it is neccesary to show that $(t\chi^{-u})(x)=\chi^u(t)\chi^{-u}(x)$, but $(t\chi^{-u})(x)=t\chi^u(t^{-1}x)$.

Comment: I apologize for the time. Regarding Q1, A toric vector bundle  $\mathcal{E}$ has an action of $T$ such that $T$ acts linearly on the fibers, and by Serre's Theorems, the vector space $H^0(X,\mathcal{E})$ is finite, so you are allowed to use  Cox Proposition. Q2, is given by the definition of an isotypical element.

Comment: Cool. Now it all makes sense. Many thanks.

Comment: After solving the first two questions, I added another one

Comment: Hi, if I am not wrong, to compute the cohomology groups, Klyachko uses Cech Cohomology, so $H^0(X,\mathcal{E})_u=\bigcap_{\sigma} H^0(U_{\sigma},\mathcal{E})_u$, using that it not too complicated realize that the image is the intersection of the images. Maybe it is important to remember that $U_{\sigma}$ is an open covering of $X$, and for this, we are allowed to use Cech Cohomology.

Comment: I see. So this also makes sense now. Thanks. I started a new [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770179/klyachkos-classification-of-toric-vector-bundles-an-ongoing-discussion) of Klyachko's theorem where I will post my elaborations and questions as I go along. I would love to continue the discussion there.

Comment: Hey @sti911, i have posted a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/463592/142626) regarding klyachko's description of cohomology which i am currently trying to understand. Maybe you have some ideas

Comment: @sagirot, my email is stroncoso1@mat.uc.cl if you want we can interchange ideas by Email